# LeJOS sample programs won't build

Tags: lego-mindstorms, lejos-nxj

I have downloaded leJOS and the eclipse addon. I set NXJ_HOME to C:\Program Files\leJOS EV3, and imported the sample programs. They don't build. They get errors on all the import lejos.* stuff. Also, I'm told that when I make my own leJOS program, it's supposed to automatically include LeJOS NXT Runtime and classes.jar. When I do it, I just get the src folder and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your project is set as a regular Java project, when it needs to be set as a leJOS NXJ project.

You can make a new leJOS NXJ project by visiting the <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>New</kbd> → <kbd>Project…</kbd> menu in Eclipse, and selecting <kbd>LeJOS</kbd> → <kbd>LeJOS NXT Project</kbd> from the list.

You can also convert an existing project to a leJOS NXJ project by right-clicking on the project name in the Package Explorer and selecting <kbd>leJOS NXJ</kbd> → <kbd>Convert to leJOS NXJ project</kbd>.

Comment: I set it as a leJOS NXT project. And I'm sure the sample projects were set as leJOS projects.